# Methods to search for a client in MySQL by ID or by phone

Tags: c#, mysql

I have this code that returns a client object, but to do it I use two methods.

How can I improve this to be more efficient and ensure it meets common standards?

```
    //Method that returns a client from a string
    private static Cliente ObtenerCliente(string query)
    {
        try
        {
            abrirConexion(); //Static method that opens a connection

            cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, mySqlConexion);
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dataReader.Read())
            {
                return new Cliente(
                    Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["id_cliente"]),
                    dataReader["nombre_cliente"].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                dataReader.Close();
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            cerrarConexion(); //Static method that closes the connection
        }
    }

    //Method that returns a customer from a phone number given
    public static Cliente ObtenerCliente_Telefono(string telefono)
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE (telefono1_cliente = '" + telefono + "' OR telefono2_cliente = '" + telefono + "');";
        return ObtenerCliente(query); //Metodo que hace la consulta
    }
    public static Cliente ObtenerCliente_Id(int id)
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM clientes  WHERE id_cliente = " + id + ';';
        return ObtenerCliente(query);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I edited your question a bit in hopes that it wouldn't be flagged as off-topic. If I significantly changed what you meant, please just let me know and we can fix it.

Comment: [Mandatory reading](https://xkcd.com/327/) for understanding [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Instead of writing ADO.NET code, why not use Dapper? https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/master/Dapper.Tests/Providers/MySQLTests.cs

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with `Cliente ObtenerCliente` accepting the query text.

Suffers from non-deterministic.  You are only going to get the first but without an `order by` then SQL will just pick one for you.

`using` is a better approach in my opinion

For sure I don't like

> Static method that opens a connection

Create the connection and let it be properly disposed

```
private static Cliente ObtenerCliente(string query)
{
    using (Connection mySqlConexion = new Connection(conString))
    {
        try
        {
            //abrirConexion(); //Static method that opens a connection
            mySqlConexion.Open();
            using (cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, mySqlConexion))
            {
                using (MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {                    
                    if (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        return new Cliente(
                        Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["id_cliente"]),
                        dataReader["nombre_cliente"].ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //dataReader.Close();  let the using dispose
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
             //cerrarConexion(); //Static method that closes the connection
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending paparazzo's answer, I would use a tertiary to return the result. I also like the descriptiveness of default rather than null:

```
return dataReader.Read()
? new Cliente(Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["id_cliente"]),
                    dataReader["nombre_cliente"].ToString())
    : default(Cliente);
```

Also consider using Top(1) in the queries, together with the order by suggestion, as the code only processes one row